# How can I use MySQL to get a list of friends based on the status of a friend request?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: members and member_requests.  When a member sends another member a friend request, a row is inserted into the member_requests table.  If the recipient accepts the request, the status is updated to 1.  If a person denies the request, it will be deleted.   I have tried many different queries  to generate a list of friends for a certain user, but none seem to work correctly.  Either the author_id of the request has to be the id of the current member, or the recipient id has to be the id of the current member.  Can someone provide a query that could do this?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/021d7/13

```
                   SELECT
                        r.request_id, r.author_id, r.recipient_id, r.status,
                        m.member_id, m.display_name
                    FROM member_requests AS r
                    LEFT JOIN members AS m ON (r.author_id = m.member_id OR r.recipient_id = m.member_id)
                    WHERE r.status = 1
                    ORDER BY m.display_name
```

Comment: Have You tried using the `NOT IN` condition? Something like `SELECT * FROM friends of member's friends WHERE friend_id NOT IN (SELECT member's direct friends)`?

Comment: If you saw my post before I edited, please read again.  I realised that the query I had was not actually getting friends, it was getting all members.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly (after Your edit) - You want to get the list of all current friends of certain member? That is - list of all the requests, that contain "me" (as an author or as a recipient of the friendship) and that have status of "1"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Then what about `SELECT author_id FROM member_requests WHERE recipient_id = ??? AND status = 1
UNION
SELECT recipient_id FROM member_requests WHERE author_id = ??? AND status = 1
` where `???` is member's id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't sound too bad at all. What you could do is get a list of all times when the user has sent a request and it was accepted, as well as a list of all times a user has received a request and it was accepted, and union those two results together.

Try this:

```
(SELECT recipient_id
FROM member_requests 
WHERE author_id = 1 AND status = 1) 
UNION
(SELECT author_id
FROM member_requests
WHERE recipient_id = 1 AND status = 1);
```

Here is your [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/021d7/27) back.

Comment: Thanks!  I will be posting another question about searching through members that aren't friends of the current member... if you want some quick rep... lol.